# jQuery - change name of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox and am looking to change it's name using jQuery

```
<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE_METHOD[]" value="SMS"> SMS
```

I would like to change it to `name="UPDATE_METHOD[1][]"` with the 1 being an auto-increment so that the next iteration becomes `name="UPDATE_METHOD[2][]"` etc...

Many thanks for any help that you can give...

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Do you have the elements already in HTML or are they created with JS?

Comment: And why would you need to do that, and do you want to change the name attribute only, or the property ?

Comment: Bit of a long story as to why this is needed, but basically a set of checkboxes are being cloned by users and the PHP needs some way to group each set of checkboxes together...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="UPDATE_METHOD[]"]').prop('name', function(i, name) {
    return name.split('[').shift() + '['+(++i)+'][]';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jJrq7/)

Comment: Thank you for this :-)  It doesn't seem to be working with my PHP code, but that could be a problem with my approach to this problem.  Will investigate further tomorrow...  Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you very much for this @adeneo  This works great although I've realised that the checkboxes need to be grouped in two.  I've posted a new question with the slightly more complex problem - looks like nothing like this has been asked before on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348662/jquery-renaming-checkboxes-sets-consecutively  Thanks for your help :-)